# How can I find unique rows in a matrix, with no element order within each row?

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique

I have an array comprising n rows and 4 colums. Each of the four entries on the row is an integer, i.e.,

```
X = [
       111 112 432   2
         6   9 115 111
       112 432 111   2

    ];
```

Each row represents the vertices of a tetrahedron. These vertices have no directionality thus, in the case above, the tetrahedra represented by X(1,:) and X(3,:) are equivalent.

I wish to remove duplicate tetrahedra from X, but can't quite figure how to incorporate the order independence into my code.

I tried the UNIQUE() function but this returns a (nx1) array of unique integers, i.e.,

```
Y = UNIQUE(X);

Y = [
     2
     6
     9
     111
     112
     115
     432
    ]
```

Anyone have any suggestions for a reasonably efficient way to complete this task?

Thanks,
S :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, sort the rows of your matrix to arrive at a "canonical" representation for the tetrahedra:

```
X = sort(X, 2);
```

Then, use `unique` with the optional `'rows'` argument to find unique rows:

```
Y = unique(X, 'rows');
```

Answer (score 5):

unique() will work on rows, but rows 1 and 3 are a different order. So we could sort them prior to using unique.

```
Y=unique(sort(X,2),'rows')

Y =

     2   111   112   432
     6     9   111   115
```

If you want to retain the original ordering then unique will return the indices

```
[Y,yi]=unique(sort(X,2),'rows');

>> X(yi,:)

ans =

   112   432   111     2
     6     9   115   111
```

Answer (score 4):

To quote from the documentation:

> b = unique(A, 'rows') returns the
>   unique rows of A.

Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

you should sort the rows first, then use unique(A,'rows') as HPM suggests